# Unable to install sgdclient on ubuntu

Tags: software-installation, dependencies, rpm

I get the below error when I try to install also i am not getting the below mentioned dependencies

```
$ rpm -i sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64.rpm
```

```
rpm: RPM should not be used directly install RPM packages, use Alien instead!
rpm: However assuming you know what you are doing...
error: Failed dependencies:
    /bin/sh is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    desktop-file-utils is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libX11.so.6()(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libXcursor.so.1()(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libXext.so.6()(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libXfixes.so.3()(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libXinerama.so.1()(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libXm.so.4()(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libXpm.so.4()(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libXt.so.6()(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libc.so.6()(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.14)(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.3)(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libc.so.6(GLIBC_2.7)(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libcurl.so.4()(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libdl.so.2()(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libdl.so.2(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libgcc_s.so.1()(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libgcc_s.so.1(GCC_3.0)(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libm.so.6()(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libpthread.so.0()(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.2.5)(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libpthread.so.0(GLIBC_2.3.2)(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    librt.so.1()(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libstdc++.so.6()(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3)(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libstdc++.so.6(CXXABI_1.3.1)(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4)(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.14)(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libstdc++.so.6(GLIBCXX_3.4.15)(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libxkbfile.so.1()(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    libz.so.1()(64bit) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
    rtld(GNU_HASH) is needed by sgdclient-5.40.941-1.el7.x86_64
```

Comment: In a debian-based linux distributions you should use " .deb " packages to install software. But if the program you want to install hasn't any " .deb " file , please consider either using [Alien](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto) to convert the rpm package to deb or just install that package in a RedHat based distro like Fedora if it's possible for you. Sometimes installing a deb packages generated by alien is difficult in ubuntu systems just because the dependencies which are easier to install from a RedHat based repository.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that The Oracle has only released an `rpm` package for `SGD Client` as well as the server. Remember in order to install a program manually in a [debian-based linux distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Category:Debian-based_distributions) you should have a `.deb` package first .

So in this case you have to either convert the `rpm` package to `deb` one using [Alien](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/RPM/AlienHowto) or to install and use that software in an [RedHat-based distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_derivatives#List_of_Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_derivatives).

I prefer the latter because it's usually (if not always) easier to install an rpm package on RedHat-based distros like Fedora just because the dependencies of them are easier to install from such a repository (vs ubuntu's ).

But in the case you just want to create a server , you can install a [Fedora](https://getfedora.org/) on VirtualBox or VMWare . There's no need to install another linux distro next to the one you currently have.